# Can't open Vuetify dialog programmatically in setTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

By default, the displaying of `Vuetify` dialog is controlled by a button toggling the value of `dialog` Boolean variable.

I was assuming that programmatically changing the value of this variable would allow to show or hide the dialog, but it doesn't. Why not?

Here's my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
      <v-card>
        Dialog content
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.dialog);
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.dialog = true;
      console.log(this.dialog);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
</script>
```

Console shows `false` on page load, then `true` after 2 seconds. But dialog still doesn't show up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use arrow function `()=>` as `setTimeout` callback :

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.dialog);
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.dialog = true;
      console.log(this.dialog);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

See the Pen 
  [Vuetify Dialog example](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/wvweRXo/)  by boussadjra ([@boussadjra](https://codepen.io/boussadjra))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 2):

you're having some trouble calling the variable inside the function of the setTimeout.

try this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
      <v-card>
        Dialog content
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    that = this
    console.log(this.dialog);
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.dialog = true;
      console.log(that.dialog);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
</script>
```

try to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) from a related issue with calling this inside anonymous functions